# Is there any way to make ChromeDriver less detectable?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using selenium and web driver for making a very simple bot, and some websites are blocking me at the door. I was wondering if there was any way to modify my chrome driver to make it less detectable. There are a couple of other questions like this for example [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/52108199?noredirect=1#comment84056917_41220267). But all the answers are all much older and I am a pretty inexperiaced programmer so I don't fully understand what they are talking about. Please let me know what you think because I am very eager to continue this project. Thanks so much!!